# How does Lorentz transforming forwards, then backwards, stay consistent?

Tags: special-relativity

Let me take you through the logic in my head...

- In frame S, you have coordinate $x$
- Transform to frame S' with velocity $v$ so the coordinate is now $x' = \gamma x$
- Now treat the S' frame as if you started there.
- Transform to a frame S'' moving at velocity $-v$. The coordinate is now $x'' = \gamma x'$
- However, S'' and S are the same frame so $x'' = x$
- So $x = \gamma x' = \gamma ^2 x$

**I would like to clarify, I'm using t=0 for everything here**

How does this make sense, what am I missing?

Comment: That's not a Lorentz transformation.

Comment: The transformation you are using is just wrong. The Lorentz boost of velocity v along the $x$-axis is given by $x'=\gamma (x-vt)$. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation

Comment: @MatteoCampagnoli But t=0.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder but $t'\neq 0$

Comment: I've edited the question, why can't you do this with t=0 for the whole thing?

Comment: Let $f(x)=x^2$. The fact that $f'(0)=0$ has nothing to do with the general fact that $f'(x)=2x$. Making an argument that $f'(0)=0$ means $f'(x)=0$ (or at least independent of $x$ is what you're effectively claiming here.

Comment: The same "paradox" arises if you put $t=0$ and $t'\neq 0$. So $t\neq 0$ is not an issue.

Comment: Perhaps it help if you improve your knowledge by reading https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation. If I had to write answer it would be a copy/paste from this page. The question that you have is caused by a lack of research.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Lorentz transformation always transfoms not only coordinates but also time. In fact you can consider it as a sort of a "rotation" in $(t,x)$ "plane".

Whe you start with an event $(0,x)$ in the new frame it will have $t'=-\gamma \frac{v}{c^2} x$, $x'=\gamma x$. You see that even though all events $(0,x)$ are simultaneous in the initial frame, in the new frame they have different $t'$. This is known as a relativity of simultaneity and in my experience most "paradoxes" in special relativity originate from people forgetting about this fact.

Now if you apply the reverse Lorentz transformation you have
$$x''=\gamma x'+\gamma v t'=\gamma^2(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2})x=x$$
Similarly you will get $t''=0$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124136/discussion-on-answer-by-oon-how-does-lorentz-transforming-forwards-then-backwar).

Answer (score -4):

The first answer gives you insight into simultaneity. Although $t'\neq 0$ everywhere in $S'$ (except for $x'=x=0$), this is not the root of the problem. Even if you take $t'\neq 0$ the paradox arises. The real problem is that you can't find, in general, the correct transformation between $S$ and $S''$ by reference to an intermediate frame $S'$ (so you can't say that $x''=\gamma (x'-vt')$). You'll get trouble indeed:

In $S'$ (for $t=0$):

$$x'=\gamma x$$
$$t'=-\gamma \frac{vx}{c^2}$$

Now assume for $x''$ ($\gamma$ is the same as in the two transformations above because $S''$ moves relative to $S'$ with speed $v$):

$$x''=\gamma (x'-vt')$$

Filling in the expressions for $x'$ and $t'$ gives:

$$x''=\gamma(\gamma x+\gamma\frac{v^2}{c^2}x),$$

so

$$x''={\gamma}^2x(1+\frac{v^2}{c^2})=\frac{1+\frac{v^2}{c^2}}{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}x,$$

which, if $x''=x$, would give:

$$x={\gamma}^2x(1+\frac{v^2}{c^2})=\frac{1+\frac{v^2}{c^2}}{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}x,$$

which is obviously nonsense (when $v=0$ the equality holds but the problem is that you have set $v=v$). So the assumption that $x''=\gamma (x'-vt')$ (as you suggest) is just wrong. You can set $x''=\gamma x'+\gamma v t'$ though, which in combination with the inverse Lorentz transformation $x=\gamma x'+\gamma v t'$ gives you $x''=x$.

This problem can only be resolved by stating the correct (and direct) transformation (for $x$) between $S''$ and $S$:

$$x''=\gamma'(x-v't),$$

where $v'$ is the relative velocity between $S$ and $S''$ (which is not the same as the sum of the relative velocities $S-S'$ and $S'-S''$, in accordance with the addition rule of velocities $v'=\frac{v+v}{1+\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$) and $\gamma'$ the with $v'$ associated Lorentz factor. This indeed gives $x=x''$ if $S''$ doesn't move relative to $S$ and, if you set $x''=x$, you get no nonsensical result but instead, you get the sensical result that $v'=0$). You can't find this transformation in the way described above.

So, to answer your question in short, you can't set $x''=\gamma x'$ (or $x''=\gamma (x'-vt')$) in the first place. When you do so you arrive at the wrong result $x''={\gamma}^2 x$ or $x''={\gamma}^2x(1+\frac{v^2}{c^2})=\frac{1+\frac{v^2}{c^2}}{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}x$. So it's your fourth "bullet" that deserves attention. Only in the special case that the velocity of $S''$ is $-v$ you can write $x''=\gamma (x'-vt')=\gamma (x'+vt')$ (giving $x''=x$). If the velocity of $S''$ were $v$ you couldn't write $x''=\gamma (x'-vt')$ though. So much ado about a minus sign...(with thanks to @J.Murray).

Comment: This answer is wrong, and the last paragraph essentially amounts to something like "the Lorentz group is not a group" or something like that.

Comment: @fqq I don't say that two Lorentz transformations performed after one another don't give a new Lorentz transformation. I just say that when you go from S to S′ and subsequently from S′ to S′′ you can't do that in the way as assumed (by assuming that x′′=γ(x′−vt′), which leads to a nonsensical result, as I've shown).

Comment: You are saying that Lorentz transformations don't have inverses/velocities cannot be added, ascribing your wrong formulas to others in the process. I will not reply further.

Comment: @ffq Where am I saying that Lorentz transformations don't have inverses (I even wrote an explicit formula for the inverse: $x=\gamma x'+\gamma v t'$) or that or that velocities can't be added? Where are the wrong formulas? The only wrong formula is to be found in the first answer: $x''=\gamma x'+\gamma v t'$. This isn't an inverse transformation.

Comment: @ffq If you say my answer is wrong, please tell me where it's wrong. It's easy to say that you won't reply anymore after stating that this answer is wrong and that I say inverses don't exist or velocities can't be added. But then you should say at least where it is wrong and where I say the things you imply that I'm saying. So, where is it wrong and where do I say the things you imply?

Comment: @fqq Or, where are my wrong formulas and where do I ascribe them to others?

Comment: OP is saying that $S''$ is moving with velocity $\color{red}{-}v$ with respect to $S'$, so the line following "Now assume for $x''$ ..." should read $x'' = \gamma(x'\color{red}{+} vt')$, which resolves the problem.

Comment: It's true that two boosts with velocities $u$ and $v$ are generally not equivalent to a boost with velocity $u+v$, but in the special case that $v=-u$, the two boosts compose to give the identity transformation.  You can see this e.g. from the velocity addition rule.

Comment: @J.Murray Indeed. How simple can it be...Thanks.